# No frost refrigerator

Tags: freezing, refrigerator, ice-cream

Can I put popsicle in no frost freezer? I bought popsicle and put in my -24c "No frost" freezer and all of my popsicle melt. Is it normal or my "No frost" freezer need service? just bought less than 3 months.

4 Door Inverter 520L RQ568N4ABU - Hisense

Comment: It is unusual that items would completely melt in a no-frost freezer.

Comment: A no-frost freezer has a heating element somewhere to melt the frost. If the popsicles are in the middle they should be fine but *possibly* against the "wrong" wall they may have a problem. But the bigger possibility is that it isn't *always* -24C. After a recent power outage I got some of [these thermometers](https://amzn.to/3IIA8nr) to be able to monitor both current temperature and high/low over time. I suggest getting something of that sort - it may be the temperature varies a lot more than you think.